# How do I adjust zoom size for a point in D3?

Tags: d3.js, zooming, transform

This could be a classic case of "you're doing it wrong", but all of my searching to date hasn't warranted any help.

Here's my scenario:

I'm using an albersUSA map projection in conjunction with the national and county GeoJson files to draw everything.

I also have a self created "cities" file that contains major cities for each state. The coordinates are accurate and everything looks good.

[image]

When a user clicks on a given state, I hide all state shapes and then calculate the transform needed to get the county shapes for that state to fit within my viewport. I then apply that transform to all the necessary county shapes in order to get the "zoomed" view. My code is as follows:

```
function CalculateTransform(objectPath)
{
   var results = '';

   // Define bounds/points of viewport
   var mapDimensions = getMapViewportDimensions();
   var baseWidth = mapDimensions[0];
   var baseHeight = mapDimensions[1];

   var centerX = baseWidth / 2;
   var centerY = baseHeight / 2;

   // Get bounding box of object path and calculate centroid and zoom factor
   // based on viewport.
   var bbox = objectPath.getBBox();
   var centroid = [bbox.x + bbox.width / 2, bbox.y + bbox.height / 2];
   var zoomScaleFactor = baseHeight / bbox.height;
   var zoomX = -centroid[0];
   var zoomY = -centroid[1];

   // If the width of the state is greater than the height, scale by
   // that property instead so that state will still fit in viewport.
   if (bbox.width > bbox.height) {
      zoomScaleFactor = baseHeight / bbox.width;
   }

   // Calculate how far to move the object path from it's current position to
   // the center of the viewport.
   var augmentX = -(centroid[0] - centerX);
   var augmentY = -(centroid[1] - centerY);

   // Our transform logic consists of:
   // 1. Move the state to the center of the screen.
   // 2. Move the state based on our anticipated scale.
   // 3. Scale the state.
   // 4. Move the state back to accomodate for the scaling.   
   var transform = "translate(" + (augmentX) + "," + (augmentY) + ")" +
                 "translate(" + (-zoomX) + "," + (-zoomY) + ")" +
                 "scale(" + zoomScaleFactor + ")" +
                 "translate(" + (zoomX) + "," + (zoomY) + ")";

   return results;
}
```

...and the binding function

```
// Load county data for the state specified.
d3.json(jsonUrl, function (json) {
    if (json === undefined || json == null || json.features.length == 0) 
    {
       logging.error("Failed to retrieve county structure data.");
       showMapErrorMessage("Unable to retrieve county structure data.");
       return false;
    }
    else 
    {
       counties.selectAll("path")
                .data(json.features)
                .enter()
                   .append("path")
                      .attr("id", function (d, i) {
                         return "county_" + d.properties.GEO_ID
                      })
                      .attr("data-id", function (d, i) { return d.properties.GEO_ID })
                      .attr("data-name", function (d, i) { return countyLookup[d.properties.GEO_ID] })
                      .attr("data-stateid", function (d, i) { return d.properties.STATE })
                      .attr("d", path);

        // Show all counties for state specified and apply zoom transform.
        d3.selectAll(countySelector).attr("visibility", "visible");
        d3.selectAll(countySelector).attr("transform", stateTransform);

        // Show all cities for the state specified and apply zoom transform
        d3.selectAll(citySelector).attr("visibility", "visible");
        d3.selectAll(citySelector).attr("transform", stateTransform);
    }
});
```

[image]

This works fine here, except for really small states, the zoom factor is much larger, and the circles get distored.

[image]

Is there a way to force the size of the points to be a fixed size (say a 15px radius) even after the transform occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting a scale transform instead of scaling the positions. You can see the difference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/eWW6s/) Basically it is the difference between:

```
// Thick lines because they are scaled too
var bottom = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'scale('+scale+','+scale+')');
bottom.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; });
```

and

```
// line thicknesses are nice and thin
var top = svg.append('g');
top.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x * scale; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y * scale; });
```

With mapping probably you best solution is to compute your offset and scale as you do and then add them into your projection function - you want to directly modify the post-projection x and y values. If you update your projection function properly you should not have to do anything else to apply the appropriate zoom to your map.

Comment: This make sense! I'll take a peek at the fiddle you provided and get it to work for my solution.

Answer (score 6):

For things you don't want to scale, just make them divided by 'scale' . In my case,

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function() {
        g.attr("transform","translate("+d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");

        g.selectAll(".mapmarker")  
        .attr("r",6/d3.event.scale)
        .attr("stroke-width",1/d3.event.scale);

});
```