# d3.js On zoom, how do you have it not effect the size of the node?

Tags: d3.js, zooming

When I zoom in on my force graph, I want to ignore the nodes as I am the links and the text.  I am having a hard time figuring out how. (I am using different SVG shapes so I can't scale "r".)  Here is my node code:

```
    //node declared as global
    node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(force.nodes()).enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function (d) { return d.Shape; }).size(150))
```

And the zoom code:

```
    function redraw(scale, trans) {
        //store the last event data
        trans = d3.event.translate;
        scale = d3.event.scale;

        text.style("font-size", (fontSize / scale) + "px");
        textEvidenceCtr.style("font-size", (fontSize / scale) + "px");
        $("line.link").css("stroke-width", getStrokeWidth); // Function so it runs for each element individually

        //transform the vis
        svg.attr("transform",
           "translate(" + trans + ")"
           + " scale(" + scale + ")"); }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep the node dimensions constant on zooming?  If that's the case you just need to set them to constants.  You don't have any reference to the nodes above so it's hard to provide any further comment - unless I'm misinterpreting the question.  If you want completely ignore the node you could style them to an opacity of 0.

Comment: Adjusted the code to show how nodes are generated

Comment: you should be able to solve this by using the scale to position your elements instead of applying a transform. Take at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141232/how-do-i-adjust-zoom-size-for-a-point-in-d3/15143307#15143307

Comment: Do you want the node to remain the same size no matter what the scale?  In that case factor by scale as in '.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function (d) { return d.Shape; }).size(150/scale))'. This is basically the same suggestion as Superboggly and also what you use to maintain the size of the text.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, that is exactly what I needed to hear.  My hand was too close to my face on this one.