# D3 Map disable zoom on city label

Tags: d3.js

i'm stuck in this problem for a few days, and i hope someone can help me.
Basically this is the problem:
I've a UK map , with city label and marker. I've enabled zoom and pan on this, but when i zoom in even marker and label grow in dimension.
I'd like to preserve marker poisiton during zoom and pan (London is always in its place) but don't scale the dimension of marker and label.

This is my zoom function

```
var zoomBehav= function(){
      var t = d3.event.translate,
          s = d3.event.scale;
      t[0] = Math.min(width / 2 * (s - 1), Math.max(width / 2 * (1 - s), t[0]));
      t[1] = Math.min(height / 2 * (s - 1) + 230 * s, Math.max(height / 2 * (1 - s) - 230 * s, t[1]));
      zoom.translate(t);
      g.style("stroke-width", 1 / s).attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ") scale(" + s + ")");
    };
```

Anyone can help me?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**
I think i should write more info. 
My svg is defined as

```
this.svg = d3.select("#"+this.config.mapContainer).append("svg")    
              .attr("id","svgMap")
              .attr("width",width)
              .attr("height",height)
              .style("background-color", "lightblue")
              .append("g").attr('id','first_g')
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")

        //Adding Zoom Rect to svg
        this.svg.append("rect")
                .attr("id", "d3e_zoomArea")
                .attr("class", "d3e_zoomArea")
                .attr("x", -width / 2)
                .attr("y", -height / 2)
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr('onmousedown', 'return false');

        //Insert g elementi in svg
        g = this.svg.append("g").attr('id','g_pathContainer');

        //Set Actual Map Right Projection
        / create a first guess for the projection
    subunits = topojson.feature(map, map.objects[level]);
    center = d3.geo.centroid(subunits);

    projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                .scale(width / 2 / Math.PI) //Crea la scala di visualizzazione
                .center(center) //Centra la posizione sulla mappa
                .translate([0, 0]);

    path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    // using the path determine the bounds of the current map and use 
    // these to determine better values for the scale and translation             
    var bounds  = path.bounds(subunits);
    var hscale  = scale*width  / (bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]);
    var vscale  = scale*height / (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]);
    scale   = (hscale < vscale) ? hscale : vscale;

    // new projection
    projection = d3.geo.mercator().center(center)
                       .scale(scale).translate([0, 0]);
    path = path.projection(projection);

        zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .translate(projection.translate())
                    .scale(projection.scale())
                    .scaleExtent([this.config.scaleRange.scaleMin , this.config.scaleRange.scaleMax])
                    .on("zoom", zoomed);
        d3.select("#first_g").call(zoom);
```

**JSFIDDLE added**
I've created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/z9S7y/) to reproduce my problem. I've applied some initial transformation to base projection in order to center and scale the map in relation to actual country.

Comment: You need to scale the projection and not the SVG, see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340).

Comment: I tried this solution, defining zoom function as in example. But map disappear totally (setting path over visibile area).
I edited my answer to give more infos. 
What i'm doing wrong?
Tks

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141232/how-do-i-adjust-zoom-size-for-a-point-in-d3/15143307#15143307

Comment: A jsfiddle would be really useful

Comment: @user1651248  Your original problem -- the lines and dots get bigger as you zoom -- is caused by using a graphical transformation to zoom.  It is fast and easy, but it zooms everything equally.  If you want help debugging a projection scale zoom function, you'll have to post that code, including the actual function (`zoomed`) that gets called to implement the zoom.

Comment: Hi guys i've edited my answer with the creation to jsfiddle example. I've tried some solution but i can't zoom in and out without rescale label and circle too. And i don't want to recalculate dimensions for every elements.
Anyone can help me?